# "file_not_found" on a file that was received from "message" event

Tags: slack-api

Situation is as follows: I'm trying to call `files.sharedPublicURL` method after receiving a `message` event from Slack Bolt. The problem is that for the one specific user (it might not be the only one, but it's the one I discovered currently), the `files.sharedPublicURL` throws `file_not_found` error no matter what file he sends. The file is showing in the Slack, so it's there, but the provided `id` is either wrong or I am missing something. Same code works flawlessly for other Slack users.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm if the user in question is not a guest or restricted user?

Comment: @SuyashGaur he's actually a workspace admin

Comment: Were you able to find the cause of your issue? Something similar is happening to me right now, only difference is that I am getting the fileid from the files.upload method.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the file[s] in question was shared in a private channel? If a file is shared in a private channel, and the user whose token the app is using to call `files.sharedPublicURL` is not a member of that private channel, they'll get a `file_not_found` error.

Comment: Files were shared in the private channel, but the bot user is in the same channel - otherwise he wouldn't be able to receive message event. Also, the same works if other user sends the message containing attachments

Comment: Yes but is`files.sharedPublicURL` being called with the user token or the bot token? Just trying to rule out the possibility that it's being called with a user token and that user is not in the channel where the files were shared.

Comment: It is called with the `user` type token which was created for the app in the Slack App console. Again, it works for other users

Comment: If your app handles OAuth it should be generating a new `xoxp` token for every user that authenticates to your app. This would explain why it works for some users but not others. `xoxp` tokens are associated to the user, not the bot. You can call `oauth.token` to verify whether the user who owns the `xoxp` token being used to call `files.sharedPublicURL` is in fact a member of the private channel where the file was shared (https://api.slack.com/methods/oauth.token)

Comment: To which user, `xoxp` token created in the Slack App console, is associated?

Comment: Ok, so. If the token is associated to the user, who registered the app in the workspace, then yes - this user is in the same private channel.

Comment: Ah ok, seems like another possible reason users could be running into errors is because you can only create public file links for files you created and/or files that are shared in a public channel. Maybe have the user try calling the API using a file id for a file they themselves have created for that private channel and see if that's successful.

Comment: The concept of my app is that it intercepts the messages from the channel and forwards them to my other app. And for attachments to work I need to publish them. So I have only one User token

Comment: Not sure what's going on but I suspect it has to do with private channel permissions and file ownership. I'd recommend making sure the user interacting with your app is both a member of the private channel and the creator of the file in question. Maybe troubleshooting those api calls in public channels will help.